# Does JNI really need interface pointer to provide multiple versions of JNI function tables

Tags: java, java-native-interface, virtual-machine

On JNI spec, it says:

> The JNI interface is organized like a C++ virtual function table or a COM interface. The advantage to using an interface table, rather than hard-wired function entries, is that the JNI namespace becomes separate from the native code. A VM can easily provide multiple versions of JNI function tables. For example, the VM may support two JNI function tables:
>
> one performs thorough illegal argument checks, and is suitable for debugging;
>   the other performs the minimal amount of checking required by the JNI specification and is therefore more efficient.

But is it really needed? After all, the interface pointer is pointer to pointer. It costs more performance recession.

Comment: Compared with the overhead of crossing the JVM/JNI boundary and of executing a JNI function call, the extra indirection is utterly insignificant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they (Sun) could have come up with some other design. This JniEnv is with us for historical reasons, and does contribute to JNI overhead, albeit not significant.

The idea was to let Java side control whether to use debugging set of functions at runtime per thread. I don't believe this idea has ever helped somebody debugging their native code.

Note that the C++ wrapper reduces the hassle significantly (sure, this is syntax only; the overhead doesn't go).